# Adding active class after being redirected to another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 `li` elements that I'm looping through, each one of them has its own HTML page. Every time a `li` element is clicked, a `class` called active gets assigned to it. That works well without redirecting to the pages, but when I add a click event and add `location.href` to it, it just redirects me to the page but the clicked element doesn't get the active class assigned to it.

Here's the code:

```js
let li = document.querySelectorAll('header ul li');

for(i=0; i<li.length; i++){
    li[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        let active = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
        active[0].className = active[0].className.replace('active', '')
        this.className += 'active'
    })
    li[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
        location.href="page2.html"
    })
    li[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
        location.href = "page3.html"
    })
    
}
```

here's the HTML:

```html
    <header>
        <ul>
            <li class="active">main page</li>
            <li>page2</li>
            <li>page3</li>
            <li>page4</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```

Comment: Note: Your `for` loop is adding the same `click` event listener to the first and second `li` elements 4 times.

Comment: When you redirect, you start fresh at the new page. None of your changes on the previous page are retained.

Comment: Save the name of the current active LI in `localStorage`. Then each page should get the name from `localStorage` and make that one active.

Comment: On a side note: Please use the `<a>` tag to navigate through pages instead of using JavaScript and `location.href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's a bit late, but as Barmar said, when you redirect, the browser refreshes and none of the changes are saved. So this can be done using `routing`, and in this case, I used Angular.